# Convert case class into string with pipe separator

Tags: scala

If I have a case class like below:

```
 case class EmployeeJobDataFields( empID: String,firstName: String,lastName: String,fullName: String)
```

And I have a data like this

```
    EmployeeJobDataFields("1043855", "Test", "User", "Test User")
```

How to convert and obtain single string with pipe separator as shown below
    "1043855|Test|User|Test User"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, of course, add a method to the `case class` that does the job, if that is what you are asking for.  You can even override `toString` if you want to.

Here is one possible implementation:

```scala
case class EmployeeJobDataFields( empID: String,firstName: String,lastName: String,fullName: String) {

  override def toString: String = Seq(empID, firstName, lastName, fullName).mkString("|")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of the fact that case classes implicitly extend [`Product`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator[Any]) which provides means of iterating over its elements

```
employee.productIterator.mkString("|")
// val res0: String = 1043855|Test|User|Test User
```

Comment: Further splitting with same separator to get Array of String employee.productIterator.mkString("|").split("|") , I am getting data like this: "1", "0", "4", "3", "8", "5", "5", "|", "T", "e", "s", "t", "|", "U", "s", "e", "r", "|", "T ..........